# Grow picturebox to top direction

Tags: c#, image, size, picturebox

Is it possible to give a picturebox a new size but instead of it growing down and right i want it to grow up and right. So basicaly I want the left bottom corner to be locked in the same position all the time.

[image]

As you can see in the image i want the green box to be above the line.
I have tried to make a formula to calculate the new position but cant figure out how to write it.

Comment: The image didnt work so here is a link https://gyazo.com/0284d67b3dcbffe5cbc2bab8a83b3fa6

Comment: Are you assigning the new size at runtime or design time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're assigning size at runtime, for example:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.pictureBox1.Size = new Size( 200, 200 );
}
```

then just handle the `PictureBox` `Resize` event:

```
private void pictureBox1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var padding = 12; //Forms designer snap-to padding.
    var titleBarHeight = 41;

    this.pictureBox1.Location = new Point(padding, this.Height - this.pictureBox1.Height - titleBarHeight - padding);
}
```

This will handle the size assignment, as well as if you've anchored the `PictureBox` and are resizing the form.

If you're just resizing at design time, then just anchor the `PictureBox`:

[image]

It'll resize where ever it's sitting on the form. As mentioned above, it'll also work automatically for form resize at run time.